# Spliterator - sized vs subsized flags

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, spliterator

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html

> SIZED Characteristic value signifying that the value returned from
>   estimateSize() prior to traversal or splitting represents a finite
>   size that, in the absence of structural source modification,
>   represents an exact count of the number of elements that would be
>   encountered by a complete traversal.
>
> SUBSIZED Characteristic value signifying that all Spliterators
>   resulting from trySplit() will be both SIZED and SUBSIZED.

1. Is there a situation when the SIZED flag is on but the SUBSIZED flag is off?
2. Is there a situation when the SUBSIZED flag is on but the SIZED flag is off?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A typical example of a `Spliterator` that is `SIZED` but not `SUBSIZED`, is the `Spliterator` created from a `HashMap`. It will maintain a range over its internal array of entries, some of these array entries being `null`, as the capacity is higher than the actual size. The exact distribution of the `null` entries to skip, depends on the hash codes of the contained keys.

So the `Spliterator` does know its (total) size initially, but when splitting the range, it doesn’t know how many elements are in each range. The more elements the `HashMap` has, the higher the likelihood of a roughly balanced split, so this strategy is reasonable, but the exact subsizes are not known and it would require an iteration over the array to find out.

Reporting a `SUBSIZED` characteristic without `SIZED` makes no sense and is, as far as I understood, not even valid.

Comment: In HashMap, If I dont know how much values equals to null, how SIZED flag is on?

Comment: `HashMap` always maintains its size, it’s a simple `int` variable. So it does know *how many* `null` values are there; it’s the difference between capacity (array length) and `size`, but it does not know, how they are distributed over the array.

Comment: @Holger if its' the internal array that is split, I guess collisions also make the subsize unknown, right? The first bucket could have 3 entries while the other ones have 0 or one, for example. Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: Thanks @Holger. Great answer, as always.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but still.. This has puzzled me some time ago too. I will enumerate the ones that I am aware of :

`HashMap` (as noted above), and as such `IdentityHashMap`, `LinkedHashMap` and `TreeMap`.

The thing to notice here is that `ConcurrentHashMap` is **not present in the list**, since it allows concurrent updates, so the size of it is actually the size at the moment of the call. As a matter of fact `CHM` does not even report `SIZED` obviously.

Then there are those that relate to `Map`, like `HashSet` and `TreeSet`, because internally these are still Maps.

And then there is one that is a bit un-expected here in the face of **BitSet** for which `BitSetSpliterator#characteristics` looks like:

```
    @Override
    public int characteristics() {
        // Only sized when root and not split
        return (root ? Spliterator.SIZED : 0) |
            Spliterator.ORDERED | Spliterator.DISTINCT | Spliterator.SORTED;
    }
```

This may look funny but the explanation is :

```
// Raise the index of this spliterator to be the next set bit
// from the mid point
index = nextSetBit(mid, wordIndex(hi - 1));
```

So for `BitSet` this would happen only once and it does not make sense to report `SUBSIZED` because the split would not happen exactly in the middle.

The other way around makes no sense at all : to report `SUBSIZED` but not `SIZED`, so no one (as far as I looked in the code) does that.